# XSLT 2.0 loop over array select elements by attribute

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt

I have an XML File what I want to transform with Saxon-CE XSLT 2.0 Processor:

```
<books>
    <book name="book1">
    <book name="book2">
    <book name="book3">
</books>
```

I want to filter this XML file by an array. This array is the result of selected checkboxes of a webpage and is passed to the XSLT with setParameter:

```
$("input:checkbox[id='books']" ).each(function() {           
    books.push($(this).val());
    });

//books: ["book1", "book2"] 

xslt = Saxon.requestXML("xsltfile.xsl");
xml = Saxon.requestXML("xmlfile.xml");
var xsltProc = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(xslt);  
xsltProc.setParameter(null, "books", books);
```

Now I want to select all books where the name occurs in the array.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="books"></xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="mybooks" select="/books/book[@name=$param[1]]"/>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I loop over the array and select only the books with the name of the array?

Comment: You have edited the sample and used the right parameter name in the reference `$books`, but I wonder why you only compare to `$books[1]` if you want to filter based on all items in your array.

Comment: I recognized the mistake when I read over the question. I changed it back in order to keep your correct answer :) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of

```
<xsl:param name="books"></xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="mybooks" select="/books/book[@name=$param]"/>
```

you would need

```
<xsl:param name="books"></xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="mybooks" select="/books/book[@name=$books]"/>
```

Other than that I don't see anything wrong in your code and according to http://saxonica.com/ce/user-doc/1.1/index.html#!api/xslt20processor/setParameter a parameter value can be a Javascript array, so hopefully that interaction between Javascript and XSLT works.